# Nonsingularity of matrix combination

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In connection to an observability problem, I have three matrices
$$ A: m \times n  \\ Q: n \times m \\ B: m \times m $$

and a combination of these, assuming $ A Q + B $ is nonsingular, as
$$ F = I_{n \times n} - Q (A Q + B)^{-1} A $$

The question is what requirement is needed on the matrices for $ F $ to be nonsingular? From "brute force" in computational software, it seems that

$$ F \; \text{singular} \Leftrightarrow B \; \text{singular} $$

but how to prove this? For the case $ m = 1 $, it is quite obvious, but for $ m \geq 2 $, it is not (for me at least).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $B$ is invertible. 
Then
$$
AF = A-AQ(AQ+B)^{-1}A = A-(AQ+B-B)(AQ+B)^{-1}A =B(AQ+B)^{-1}A.
$$
Let $x$ be such that $Fx=0$. Then $AFx=0$, and by the above representation $Ax=0$ since $B$ is invertible. By definition of $F$ it follows $Fx = x$, hence $x=0$. And thus, $F$ is invertible.

Let me prove the reverse implication. Assume that $F$ is invertible. With the same trick as above
$$
FQ = Q - Q(AQ+B)^{-1}AQ = Q - Q(AQ+B)^{-1}(AQ+B-B)=Q(AQ+B)^{-1}B.
$$
Take $x$ such that $Bx=0$. Then the above equation implies $Qx=0$ since $F$ is assumed to be invertible. This implies $(AQ+B)x=0$. By assumption $AQ+B$ is invertible, hence $x=0$, and $B$ is invertible.

This proves that $F$ is invertible if and only if $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: daw, you proved that if $B$ invertible then $F$ is invertible, is it true also the opposite direction? if yes, then how to show this. I must say that the proof above is ingenious.

Comment: Nice trick, did you learn it in a course or a book in Control theory?

Comment: @MathematicalPhysicist Cant remember where I learned this. It is kind of standard when dealing with inverses of sums of two operators/matrices.

Comment: Nice. This will be very useful for the problem I'm solving. Thanks!